# Python version 3.10 generating a error when trying to add a watermark to an image

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, watermark

Note: all 3.9 versions run the code perfectly creating the watermarked image.

I created this project to fit a watermark cross that perfectly fits the size of the image, but in this line of code:

```
paste_mask = watermark.split()[3].point(lambda i: i * TRANSPARENCY / 100.)
```

It generating this error:

```
File "c:\Users\Computador\Desktop\Python\Watermark.py", line 29, in watermark_with_transparency
paste_mask = watermark.split()[3].point(lambda i: i * TRANSPARENCY / 100.)
File "C:\Users\Computador\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 1723, in point
return self._new(self.im.point(lut, mode))
TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

The complete code is:

```
from PIL import Image

def watermark_with_transparency(input_image_path,
                                output_image_path,
                                watermark_image_path):
    TRANSPARENCY = 10
    angle = 30
    base_image = Image.open(input_image_path)
    w_img, h_img = base_image.size
    basewidth = w_img
    watermark = Image.open(watermark_image_path)
    watermark = watermark.rotate(angle, expand=True)
    wpercent = (basewidth / float(watermark.size[0]))
    hpercent = h_img / float(watermark.size[1])
    if wpercent < hpercent:
        hsize = int((float(watermark.size[1]) * float(wpercent)))
        watermark = watermark.resize((basewidth, hsize), Image.ANTIALIAS)
    else:
        wsize = int((float(watermark.size[0]) * float(hpercent)))
        watermark = watermark.resize((wsize, h_img), Image.ANTIALIAS)
    w_logo, h_logo = watermark.size
    center_y = int(h_img / 2)
    center_x = int(w_img / 2)
    top_y = center_y - int(h_logo / 2)
    left_x = center_x - int(w_logo / 2)
    if watermark.mode != 'RGBA':
        alpha = Image.new('L', (w_img, h_img), 255)
        watermark.putalpha(alpha)
    paste_mask = watermark.split()[3].point(lambda i: i * TRANSPARENCY / 100.)
    base_image.paste(watermark, (left_x, top_y), mask=paste_mask)
    base_image.save(output_image_path)
```

The model in the image is ok and the values in my view are correct, what should i modify to work in this new python version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
paste_mask = watermark.split()[3].point(lambda i: int(i * TRANSPARENCY / 100.))
```

Seems that in when moving to `Python 3.9`, the `type inference` changed and the values did not automatically cast into `int`.

Comment: First of all, thanks for your attention, but when i try, the error remains.

Comment: point seems to expect an `int`.  try now

Comment: It worked perfectly @YScharf, according to stackoverflow best practices, it would be interesting if you add an explanation even if it is minimal of what changed from 3.9 to 3.10 that generated this error, so that future people and I can understand what has changed. If you can and it won't bother you, of course!